# Appearance of extraneous characters in ipython

Tags: ipython

What is with the extraneous characters showing up before I am even finished typing, i.e., “ ….: “?

```
In [21]: with open('os_walk_align.txt', 'w') as f:                                                                                
In [21]: with open('os_walk_align.txt', 'w') as f:                                                                                
....:     for root, dir,    ....:     for   ....:    ....:    ....:    ....:                                                   
....:     for root, dir, file in os.walk(spath):                                                                               
....:         pri   ....:         print(roo   ....:         print(root, file=f)                                                
....:
```

python 3.4.3
visual studio code 1.6.1
ipython 3.0.0

ps - I looked at http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.9.1/html/interactive/reference.html but I typed this in by hand, I did not paste. I also realized Ipython is now up to 5 for 2.7 and 6 for <3.3, so I will update that.

Comment: That's weird. If you still see it with up to date IPython: is this in a terminal pane, or some other interface in VS Code?

Comment: @thomas-k I decided I have too many other things to do to chase this down. When I went to upgrade ipython, I discovered the jupyter notebook, which, in addition to having a terminal, includes Sublime for text editing. So I'm done with my VS Code experiment and have had no issues so far with the notebook.